# Schedule task in Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

i was trying to schedule one application in Windows 2008 server. and i can see that the schedeule is showing running in the task Scheduler, but nothing is happening(i mean the program that i scheduled is not working) and the schedule is not stopping also(i specificaly choose if the schedule runing more than 3 hours stop it automatically) i went through several links and im sure im scheduling it in proper way. is anybody facing this problem on Windows 2008? any resolution. Appreciate your feedback.

Regards
Joseph

Answer (score 1):

Thanks resolove my issue. becuase on windows server 2008 need full path while raring:
On my scenario i schediled a batch  script to zip one file everyday,but it didnt work as below my old script:
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a test.rar test.txt    : this didnt work

and i added the full path on my batch file and the below script works for me on windows 2008 server;
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a F:\ziptest\test.RAR F:\ziptest\test.txt    : this works fine

Hope this wil help some one using Winrar on windows 2008 server and calling a batch script

Joseph

Answer (score 0):

What program do you have running? If it is a batch script, ensure there isn't a `pause` at the end.

Also check the Scheduled Task log under **Scheduled Tasks -> Advanced (Menu) -> View Log**. It can provide a lot of insight into what happened or what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Im calling A batchfile. it is calling a Winrar script to rar a file.(this is my SQL Server Backup .daily basis im calling this batch file from scheduled task. But its showINg WINRAR is running on Task manager. but its not exiting and nothing happening. if i run the batchfile manually this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joseph..

I had the same problem but now it works fine :)

My batch file:

```
exp xx/xx@ibb05 full=y buffer=32768 file=D:\EXPORT\FULL%date%.DMP  
d:\export\rar.exe a d:\EXPORT\FULL%DATE%.rar FULL D:\EXPORT\FULL%date%.DMP -r
del D:\EXPORT\DB\FULL%date%.DMP
```

All can use this commands in batch file with Task schedule on Server 2008